# Difference between "coche" and "carro"

Tags: significado, diferencias-regionales, diferencias-entre-palabras

I have always wondered what is the difference between 'coche' and 'carro'.

I have done some googling on it but still can't understand.

Can anyone explain it and give me some examples please!! :)

Comment: "carro" is used only in "Latin America", "auto" is used only in Chile, Argentina, and Uruguay, and "coche" and "automóvil" can be used anywhere.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Spain we favor `coche` for a car, while a `carro` is more like a four wheeled cart (similar to the word `carreta`, which is a smaller, two wheeled cart), the one that would use horses or mules to pull it.

[image]

In most Latin American countries the word `carro` designates a car (automobile). It is just a regional difference. If `carro` is used in Spain to designate an automobile the word is considered slang.

Comment: Gracias mucho. Yo entiendo ahora!

Comment: @Tia27 Se diría "Muchas gracias. Ya lo entiendo" o "Muchas gracias, ahora lo entiendo".

Answer (score 8):

If you come to **Chile**, you will notice that these words have very specific uses:

> **Coche**: the one used for carry babies.
>
> **Carro**: which is used to buy in the supermarket (or Internet).

Both words can be used to refer to the train *wagons*. None of them means *car*, like in other countries.

Comment: Then, what do you use for *car*?

Comment: In Chile: informal _auto_, formal _automóvil_.

Answer (score 2):

En mi sitio, el estado de California, la palabra "carro" tiene dos significados: coche y otro es carro de compras. Algunos dicen "carrito"